# angular.extend doesnt work in Angularjs app to merge 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I wanna merge two arrays but the result always is null. I dont know whats the problem here is my code :

```
$scope.messages=[];
$scope.messagesRecieved=[];
$scope.messagesSent=[];
Message.getMessengerMessages(localStorage.getItem("token"),localStorage.getItem("contact")).then(function(messages){


 $scope.messagesRecieved=messages;

})
console.log('le contact est '+localStorage.getItem("contact") +'Lutilisateur est  '+localStorage.getItem("token"))
Message.getMessengerMessages(localStorage.getItem("contact"),localStorage.getItem("token")).then(function(messages){


 $scope.messagesSent=messages;
 for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
  if(messages[i].read=='no'){
    Message.modifyRead(messages[i]._id);
  }
 }
})
angular.extend( $scope.messages, $scope.messagesRecieved, $scope.messagesSent);
```

Message is a service.

Comment: The `Message` API is asynchronous. Push the data to `$scope.messages` array from *inside* each `.then` block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you only use `$scope.messagesRecieved` and `$scope.messagesSent` as intermediates, for deriving `$scope.messages`, not for driving the view.

If so, they can disappear and `messagesRecieved`/`messagesSent` can be delivered down a promise chain starting with `Promise.all()` to aggregate your two `Message.getMessengerMessages()` promises.

Also, to concatenate arrays, use `newArray = array1.concat(array2)`.

```
// $scope.messagesRecieved = []; // not necessary unless there's a corresponding view element
// $scope.messagesSent = []; // not necessary unless there's a corresponding view element
$scope.messagesSent = []; // you only need to do this if you want to nullify a view element while the two async gets are underway.

var receivedPromise = Message.getMessengerMessages(localStorage.getItem('token'), localStorage.getItem('contact'));

var sentPromise = Message.getMessengerMessages(localStorage.getItem('contact'), localStorage.getItem('token')).then(function(messages) {
    for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
        if(messages[i].read == 'no') {
            Message.modifyRead(messages[i]._id); // if Message.modifyRead() is async, this code block is a bit different
        }
    }
});

Promise.all(receivedPromise, sentPromise).then(function(messagesRecieved, messagesSent) {
    $scope.messages = messagesRecieved.concat(messagesSent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) is used to merge *objects*, not arrays. You probably want to use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) here.

```
$scope.messages = $scope.messages
                        .concat($scope.messagesRecieved)
                        .concat($scope.messagesSent);
```

Comment: @julianaMorales That is not enough information for me to work with. Could you elaborate on _how_ it failed?

Comment: when i display $scope.messages on the view its empty